# Create release zip file on Github without tag name in it

Tags: php, wordpress, git, github, release

I have this repo on Github - https://github.com/ronakg/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin. It's a wordpress plugin for creating a photo gallery from your photos stored on Flickr.

Now what I want to achieve is - when I create a new release zip for my plugin, it should not use the tag name.

For example, I create releases 3.5.0 and 3.6.0. The folder structure for both the releases should be same.

```
awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin
  /index.php
  /README.txt
  .
  .
```

Right now it creates the release zipfiles like this:

```
awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin-3.5.0
   /index.php
   /README.txt
   .
   .
```

This is important for me as I want to serve this zip files directly as WordPress plugin updates for my users. This different file structure breaks the plugin update process in WordPress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced [a similar problem](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker/issues/1) with the prefix `-master` and solved with the following filter `upgrader_source_selection`. My repository is `github-plugin-for-wordpress`, adjust for your own.

```
/**
 * Access this plugin’s working instance
 *
 * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
 * @return  object of this class
 */
public function plugin_setup()
{
    add_filter( 'upgrader_source_selection', array( $this, 'rename_github_zip' ), 1, 3);
}

/**
 * Removes the prefix "-master" when updating from GitHub zip files
 * 
 * See: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker/issues/1
 * 
 * @param string $source
 * @param string $remote_source
 * @param object $thiz
 * @return string
 */
public function rename_github_zip( $source, $remote_source, $thiz )
{
    if(  strpos( $source, 'github-plugin-for-wordpress') === false )
        return $source;

    $path_parts = pathinfo( $source );
    $newsource = trailingslashit( $path_parts['dirname'] ) . trailingslashit( 'github-plugin-for-wordpress' );
    rename( $source, $newsource );
    return $newsource;
}
```

Comment: I don't have problem with the zip file name, WordPress handles it perfectly fine. The problem is with the deflated directory that gets created after extraction. I want it to always create awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin and not include the tag name at the end.

Comment: This code does exactly this, IIRC the zip file arrives with a suffix in the temp `wp-content/upgrade` folder, hence deflates with a suffix.

Comment: It works in your case because you are always creating the zip from master. I want to create release zips from tag names. So what happens is, when the zip is deflated, it shows up as new plugin. The old plugin instance gets deactivated and removed, and user has to active the updated plugin again.

Comment: I'm positive it's a simple matter of adjusting the search/replace inside the method, did you try to debug it?

Comment: Yes it worked. I just didn't try enough the last time. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to be able to set a fixed folder name - for example if I had plugin-master(1).zip we would want this also to extracted to /plugin/ - am I right and thinking this will only work with plugin-master.zip? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @raison, this should work for any suffix added by GitHub on their zip file.